# Switch edit pencil direction for comments edited by other-than-attributed-author

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, user-interface, moderator-tools

In [this discussion](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1361/20777), the issue was raised that moderators' ability to edit comments sometimes results in a situation where a mod is putting words in a user's mouth or having them say something different than what they actually said.  While rare, it does happen, and while most mod comment edits do not significantly change the meaning beyond removal of profanity etc., any that do wind up causing a significant difference get buried or not noticed as such as a result.  Folks over at [Law.SE](http://law.stackexchange.com) might be able to elaborate further on why this matters.

[Mod J.R. suggests](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1361/mod-edited-comments?rq=1#comment3338_1365) a subtle notice that a mod edited the comment, such as an "edited" pencil that leans the other way (e.g. ✎); hovertext could also be changed.  I would suggest something simple, e.g. one bit, flipped if the comment was ever edited by anyone other than the author the comment is attributed to.   Then mods who write and edit their own comments don't have markings any different than regular users, beyond the blue diamond already there, but it is knowable if the comment should be completely attributable to the author or if there were other factors in what is attributed to that author in that comment.

This meta post formalizes that suggestion.

Comment: I think this might cause more harm than good. Without revisions, people will start to guess and speculate, and throw accusations. It's bad enough as it stands as they can't know who edited, but if they'll know it's a moderator it might antagonise them even more.

Comment: And getting back to a very common reason why we never do anything with these: moderators rarely ever edit others' comments. The number of cases this would affect is so incredibly small that all the work that would be required to make this happen is disproportionately inappropriate. If there are problems with comment editing that would *require* such a feature, we'd be far more likely to just not allow moderators to edit comments, and instead force them to be deleted if they're not useful without editing.

Comment: Even if "rarely" is a tiny percentage, across the SE network, it's probably still more than several times a day.  Currently, the community does not have a check to be able to find out when it's happening, so they couldn't even find problems if any existed.